# SQL Server seems to be ignoring specified backup file extension

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2017

I have created a maintenance plan using the Wizard and this is the SQL produced, per SSMS:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [FOO] TO  DISK = N'C:\SQLBAKS\FOO\FOO_backup_2019_08_09_161656_6414445.diff'  
WITH DIFFERENTIAL , NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'FOO_backup_2019_08_09_161656_6414445', 
SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, 
STATS = 10
```

The resulting files do not have a ".diff" extension but ".bak"

I am trying to differentiate FULL backups from DIFFERENTIALS in the filename.

Answer (score 1):

When you go through the wizard you should

1. Click the differential option and
2. Specify diff in the **Backup file extension** on the **Destination Tab**
   (it's bak by default, even for differential)

Most people aren't fans of maintenance plans since you are kind of blindly turning over
some control and they create SSIS packages which aren't fun to troubleshoot. Ola's scripts are super easy, well documented, and have a ton of options. You can always roll your own via Agent Jobs too.

Comment: Yes, `Backup file extension on the Destination Tab` was where I had specified **diff** originally.  Unless that is not the actual script being executed, it's being ignored.

Comment: Quite possible, which is why most people dodge maintenance plans. However, I just followed the steps i produced above and it spits it out as .diff. Also, if you go into your maintenance plan, right above your "View T-SQL" button in the back up task you *should* see `diff` in the backup extension. So, your version has a bug or you are mistaken. I am on Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM)